# How do I import the Telegram Bot API from rubenlagus in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm want to start coding Telegram Bot's using the Telegram Bots Api 5.2.0 by rubenlagus and I'm having trouble getting it imported into my project in Eclipse.

https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

I have no idea what Maven or Gradle even is or does so I tried the 4. suggested option to import the library, downloaded and imported the file 'telegrambots-5.2.0-jar-with-dependencies' but it was incomplete and lacking following classes (maybe more but those are the ones I tried to use and could't find):

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot
org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramWebhookBot
org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi
```

So what do I have to do to import the whole library into my project using Eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

Using ***Maven*** :-
Try Importing maven dependency in your *pom.xml* file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
   <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Using ***Gradle*** :-

```
implementation 'org.telegram:telegrambots:5.2.0'
```